# Parse to parse server end to end documentation

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, migration, parse-server, mlab

Here I would like to document the steps involved to migrate from Parse.com to parse server which includes database migration, password reset, cloud code, push notifications etc.

There were few minor issues which are covered in this step documents. Any different suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve recently did migration for my apps which were hosted on the Parse.com, so thought to put all steps together here for different parts of the migrations. Parse itself has great documentation on [Github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform), with some minor changes, you should be able to use that documentation. Here I’m covering the parts which may be questions for newbies who don’t know much about Node.js or overall backend and any issues I came across during migration. I covered below topics, each one of the link will take to detailed step document I've written on the blog.

1. [Migrate from Parse.com to Parse server on Heroku & mLab](https://leapforwards.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/migrate-from-parse-com-to-parse-server-on-heroku/)
2. [Hosting Parse Dashboard](https://leapforwards.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/hosting-parse-dashboard/)
3. [Password reset & Email verification using Parse Server](https://leapforwards.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/password-reset-email-verification-using-parse-server/)
4. [Cloud code on Parse server](https://leapforwards.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/cloud-code-on-parse-server/)
5. [Push notification using Parse Server](https://leapforwards.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/push-notification-using-parse-server/)